# nodejs crypt cipher aes256 max data size

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography, aes

Hi want to use module crypt from nodejs to crypt some data

here my code

```
toCrypt = "message";

var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes256', key);
cipher.update(toCrypt, 'utf-8', 'base64');

var nowItisCrypted = cipher.final('base64');


var deCipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes256', key);
deCipher.update(nowItisCrypted,'base64','utf-8');

var unCrypted =  deCipher.final('utf-8');
```

the size of caracters that can be contain in message variable depend of key size. 
if I send a too long code I got the following error :

```
TypeError: error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length
at Decipher.Cipher.final (crypto.js:287:27
```

Does anyone can tell me the relation between key size and message size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no direct relation between key size and message size. Key size is not the same thing as block size, which will be 128 for AES, regardless of the key size. Even then the block size only matters if a block mode of operation is being used. As you are using CBC the block size *is* being used.

The problem with the code above is not the block size or the key size however. Check out the documentation of the `Cipher.update()` method:

> Returns the enciphered contents, and can be called many times with new data as it is streamed.

The problem is that you are assuming that the data that *may* be returned by the `Cipher.update()` method can be discarded. That is only true if all the data is being returned by the call to `Cipher.final()`.

Now normally you would not get this exception if you output raw bytes of data; the data returned is always x times the block size for either the `Cipher.update()` or `Cipher.final()` methods. Any sane implementation simply returns data after a block has been encrypted. So you would just decrypt the last block without error.

The additional issue here is that base 64 encoding does not work with block sizes or powers of 2. It encodes 3 bytes into 4 characters. In other words, the `Cipher.final()` may return a few characters more than an entire block. Now the decryption routine is asked to decrypt a few bytes more than an entire block, so it will fail.

So finally the solution; you should create a concatenation of the ciphertext returned by the consecutive calls to `Cipher.update()` and `Cipher.final()`.

Comment: Just one other little question.. Is it something good to do to crypt data send and received by an api with the previous method or it is not necessary.

Comment: That depends on the *use case*, in 99% of the *use cases* it is better to opt for TLS. The code above is not secure for sending ciphertext if a padding oracle is present at the receiving side; the receiving side should verify a (H)MAC before decryption. These kind of issues are not present in TLS, so please do not create your own secure transport layer security.